# Create two new columns where the second is the leftover

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create two new columns in my dataframe. Where the first column of houseNumber only extracts the houseNumber in a new column. I can do this (see column numbers). I want a new column after numbers, where the values of this column can sometimes be empty.

See below the outcome I wish.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'houseNumber':['13', '14-A', '13B', '2-15', '1-15', '1B15', '22 A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df= df.assign(numbers= df['houseNumber'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int))
```

How could achieve this result below?

```
houseNumber  numbers   afterNumbers
0          13       13    #no value(comment)  
1        14-A       14    -A
2         13B       13    B
3        2-15        2    -15
4        1-15        1    -15
5        1B15        1    B15
6        22 A       22     A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` with this `function`.

```
def split_number(string):
    num = ""
    i = 0

    for s in string:
        if s.isdigit():
            num+=s
            i+=1
        else:
            break

    if i == len(string):
        return pd.Series([int(num), ""])
    else:
        return pd.Series([int(num), string[i:]])


df[['numbers', 'afterNumbers']] = df.apply(lambda row: split_number(row.houseNumber), axis=1)

  houseNumber  numbers afterNumbers
0          13       13             
1        14-A       14           -A
2         13B       13            B
3        2-15        2          -15
4        1-15        1          -15
5        1B15        1          B15
6        22 A       22            A
```